# Bitbucket Server Pull Request

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-fork

So here is my situation and hopefully someone can clarify my thought process:

> 1. I have a private **bitbucket** server
> 2. I have a user who has only read-access
> 3. He makes a new **local branch**, does his work, now he is ready for a pull request
> 4. Error: Bitbucket create **pull request needs two branches on the same repo** to do its pull request but the "dev" cannot push his branch since
>      he has only read-access not write access

My question, how can I create a pull request using Bitbucket to
A, send this local branch to be reviewed by my team
B, and I want to have this "dev" to only have read-access?

Comment: Bitbucket pull requests [should work across forks](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/how-it-works). Where are you seeing this error message? How did you trigger it?

Comment: Am I mistaken? Should not the "dev" clone the repo, commit and then ask for a pull request? His work cannot be public

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, Robert. Did your developer create a fork or a branch to work in?

Comment: Sorry let me restate the problem from step 1. First he cloned our repo, second he created a local branch, now he wants to make a pull request but bitbucket requires me to use two remote branches but I want the pull request to use the local branch my dev made and then I want to use our remote master branch as well

Comment: @Chris I believe you are on the right track with forking. So workflow should be like this: 1 Fork 2 Commit changes 3 Ask for pull request between your branch and master. Although now I am wondering how easy it will be for our dev to rebase to our new commits to our master since he forked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Solution 1 Handle branches permissions

I suggest you create the branch in the bitbucket server first, with writing permissions (this is normally done using Jira, so you can assign a task ID to the branch).

To handle branches and permissions check this [guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html). You can define a pattern with associated permissions so certain branches automatically adopt those properties.

Then the user would do

```
$ git fetch origin
$ git checkout feature/taskID-whatever
```

After developing he would be able to push the branch, and perform a pull request to develop.

```
$ git push origin feature/taskID-whatever
```

Develop must be only read, but branches not.

### Solution 2 Use fork

In the same [tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/) you are following you will find how to do a **fork**. This way your developer will have a clone in his own bitbucket repository.

Comment: This would work but I want it to be done as a clone. I am using this article https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/ and it states that this pull request should be possible if he pushes the branch. I just do not want devs to be able to touch this "stable code repo" by granting write access to them

Comment: I don't think you can create per-branch write permissions in Bitbucket from JIRA. If you can, please provide instructions or a link.

Comment: You can pre-establish branch permissions. https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-branch-permissions-776639807.html
The other solution of course will be a fork, but I don't like this solution for a developer of a team.

Comment: @Jav_Rock, I may have been unclear. I know that Bitbucket supports branch permissions. I was asking about the part I've bolded here: "I suggest you create the branch in the bitbucket server first, with writing permissions (**this is normally done using Jira**, so you can assign a task ID to the branch)." Are you suggesting that a branch can be created in Bitbucket, with specific permissions, _by performing some task in JIRA_?

Comment: Yes. If you define a pattern for a branch permissions, every branch you create that matches the pattern will have those permissions, it does not matter if you create the branch from Jira or from Bitbucket.